# Access UITableViewCell label.text from sender iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, sender

I have an `UITableView` which loads each cell's content programmatically. Specifically, it draws an `UILabel`, named *nameLabel* and sets the **label.text** property with some text that it gets from our server. I have a `UIButton` which is then programmatically drawn over the UILabel so that when the user taps the text, it triggers an **@selector** method that looks like this:

```
- (void) nameButtonInvoked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"nameButton Clicked..");

    UIViewController *nameView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"namePageView"];
    [self presentViewController:nameView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I would like to pass the actual text in *nameLabel* to the presented ViewController, **nameView**, which I will do with `prepareForSegue`. But to do this, I need to access that programmatic `UILabel`'s **.text** property from either the **@selector** method using **sender**, or I need to somehow set a global variable to be equal to that label's text by detecting which cell is being used. Since the `UIButton` is the sender, I'm assuming I may have to make the UILabel work like a button with the *touchUpInsideEvent* so that I can access the label's text property through sender. How do I do this?

Currently I have a global variable named *selectedNameString* which I need to set to be equal to that nameLabel.text, that needs to be done in the @selector method so that my prepareForSegue method can pass the data to the next VC.

Comment: Why add a button over a label? What does that give you that you can't do with a button alone? Just set the button's title with the data from your server. Also, if you want prepareForSegue to be invoked, you need to call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: from your button, not presentViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply add a Tap gesture recognizer to your label and call the method which you are currently calling by use of button which is not required in your case.

```
[ self.nameLabel addGestureRecognizer:[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(nameButtonInvoked:)];
```

And you can access the associated text of UILabel with help of [sender view] 's text as :

```
- (void) nameButtonInvoked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"nameButton Clicked..");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];
}
```

Assuming you already marked a segue in storyboard from current view controller to 'namePageView' view controller  and set the segue's identifier as "MySegue".

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {

        // Get destination view(your namePageView view controller)
        SecondView *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Get your label text here
        NSString* labelText=((UILabel*)[sender view]).text;

         // Pass the information to your destination view
         [vc setSelectedText:labelText];
    }
}
```

Also you must have one method in 'namePageView' view controller to get the text you are passing like this:

```
-(void)setSelectedText:(NSString*)text;
```

Comment: Very nice. It was that pointer cast on `[sender view]` I had no idea about. This is definitely efficient, let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to set each button's `tag` property to the cell's `indexPath.row` (assuming you have only one section) and then use `sender.tag` in your `nameButtonInvoked` method to access your table's data array.

To avoid casting, you can also declare that method as `-(void)nameButtonInvoked:(UIButton*)sender`